# How can I track server time outs programmatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, error-handling, connection-timeout

We have a page that accepts video file uploads using a plain `<input type="file"` . We have had users (students in this case) complain that it's not working but not provide any type of error message or anything. If indeed there is a problem, I believe it would be a timeout error from trying to upload a large file on a bad connection. Is there anyway to track this to find out what they are trying to do and what the problem is?

Comment: What's your error handling like? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe they are trying to upload files larger than the maximum allowed file size or the request timeouts which could be controlled by the following section in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="20000" />
</system.web>
```

Also the server's EventLog probably contains some errors which could give you more clues.

Another useful thing is to subscribe for the `Application_Error` event in your `Global.asax` and try to trace all unhandled exceptions which might occur:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = app.Context;
    Exception ex = context.Server.GetLastError();
    // TODO : use your favourite logging framework to trace the exception
    // so that you can later see what went wrong. At least you should get
    // the exception stacktrace.
}
```